# Flutter - iron source can't load banner - loadBanner already called and still in progress

Tags: flutter, ironsource

i am using [this](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_ironsource_x) iron source plugin

error :
E/ironSourceSDK: API(30848): L a - can't load banner - loadBanner already called and still in progress

and i show my banner like this

```
     bottomNavigationBar:
          IronSourceBannerAd(keepAlive: true, listener: IronBannerAdListener()),
```

how can i dispose/destroy iron source banner in flutter?
my banner ad listener

```
class IronBannerAdListener extends IronSourceBannerListener {
  @override
  void onBannerAdClicked() {
    print("onBannerAdClicked");
  }

  @override
  void onBannerAdLeftApplication() {
    print("onBannerAdLeftApplication");
  }

  @override
  void onBannerAdLoadFailed(Map<String, dynamic> error) {
    print("onBannerAdLoadFailed");
  }

  @override
  void onBannerAdLoaded() {
    print("onBannerAdLoaded");
  }

  @override
  void onBannerAdScreenDismissed() {
    print("onBannerAdScreenDismisse");
  }

  @override
  void onBannerAdScreenPresented() {
    print("onBannerAdScreenPresented");
  }
}
```

how can i get help from this listener class?

Answer (score 2):

If you are moving back and forth form one activity to another than you have to destroy the banner, always destroy banner before loading a new banner,

so while going form activity A to B  destroy banner in A than go to B and load the  in B.
and while coming back form B to A than also destroy in B and again reload the banner in A

***in case of Android***
you can use onBackPressed to destroy the banner

```
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        IronSource.destroyBanner(banner);
        finish();
    }
```

If there is a backbutton on nav bar

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            IronSource.destroyBanner(banner);
            finish();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

this may vary in your case `android.R.id.home`